# C2DM unstableness or limitation of some kind?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have a working C2DM project, atm. I have me and my colleagues phones registered and it has worked very well so far.
Though today we were both doing testing with it, which resulted in us having to wait a really long time for these messages to appear on our phone, and even some that were never delivered.

We are talking a bout ~100 messages to 2 devices in an ½-1 hour...

Anyone have any clue if this could be Google issues or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well within reason. C2DM is not a guaranteed message delivery service. It is certainly not designed for "~100 messages to 2 devices in an ½-1 hour". That sort of message rate calls for something like XMPP, where you are maintaining a persistent socket connection.

Comment: Yeah i know that, it was also just while running a heavy amount of tests, but then we had to demonstrate it afterwards where it didnt work, because messages didn't appear, which really wasn't my proudest moment :-/
But do you know if there is something @ google that prohibits this kind of behavior?

Comment: @AndersMetnik: I seem to recall some rate limits, but I don't remember the details. Most people are worried about overall usage caps more. But C2DM *will* drop messages as a matter of course. Apps should use C2DM as an optimization, to go get data sooner than they might on a regular polling interval.

Comment: so you suggest having a polling next to C2DM ? If yes, wouldn't that ruin the power saving that we yield from C2DM?

Comment: @AndersMetnik: "so you suggest having a polling next to C2DM ?" -- Google certainly does. "If yes, wouldn't that ruin the power saving that we yield from C2DM?" -- the only "power saving" I am aware of is in comparison to you having a 24x7 service with a permanent socket connection to a server. C2DM *may* let you reduce your polling frequency (e.g., once a day rather than once every 15 minutes), but any non-guaranteed-delivery mechanism is not a replacement for polling.

Answer (score 0):

How big are your messages? My understanding is the payload for C2DM is 1kb or less.

Comment: As said, it works fine, our payload well within the acceptable range :) only have 1 data. and that's about 8bytes